# How do you retrieve form posted values via data-attributes with vb.net?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm referencing this post here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2656

```
<button class="delete" data-url="/delete-url/file.jpg" data-data='{"db_name":"your_db"}'>Delete</button>
```

In my case I need to send a comma separated string of versions.

In vb.net I am trying to use typical:

```
Context.Request.Form("versions")
```

But it's empty. I'm probably doing something wrong.

I've tried the following formats in the button's data-attribute:

```
data-versions="version1,version2,version3"
data-versions='{"versions":"version1, version2,version3"}'
data-attributes='{"versions":"version1,version2,version3"}'
```

Looking in the network tab I don't see any posted form values. It's set to type POST, but all it sees are some query string variables.

I can switch to passing via querystring but was hoping to keep it as a form posted value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking for data-data attribute.

```
data-data='{"versions":"version1,version2,version3"}'
```

Comment: That didn't work... at first, and then I found out what my problem was. I was trying to use the data-attribute on the TOP delete button instead of on the individual delete buttons displayed next to uploaded files. The Top delete button simply activates delete on each file. Thank you. This answer was correct though.